# AWS Profile on command line prompt

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

A common prompt for the command line is the following:

`username@host:~$ Here goes your command`

With oh-my-zsh you can tune the command line with the current git branch and more tuning options and having a prompt like this:

`~/my-awesome-repo (main) Here goes your command`

I work with multiple AWS accounts and sometimes bypassing the `--profile` parameter with the wrong profile can lead to big problems and even bigger if I forget the parameter, for that reason I change the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable each time I need to switch accounts.

I want to know if there is an optimal option in oh-my-zsh with a theme/plugin/configuration that can change my prompt to include the current default AWS_PROFILE environment variable and having something like this:

`my-aws-profile ~ Here goes your command`

I tried modifying my current theme (zsh2000) adding a function that parse the output of `aws configure list` with `awk` but it was extremelly slow since it executes the function for every command and it could take 2-4 seconds, so I want to know if there is a more optimal solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

oh-my-zsh has a aws plugin that will display what profile you're using in the prompt.

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/aws/aws.plugin.zsh